# How to do horizontal scroll using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

I want to perform horizontal scroll using on this [site](https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/5day/l/USID0011:1:US)

1) First reduce the browser size until you will see table scroll bar.

I have done with following code snippet, but it didn't work for me well.

```
driver.get("https://weather.com/en-IN/weather/5day/l/USID0011:1:US");
Dimension d = new Dimension(521,628);
driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My code is working well till now, but my execution is getting stopped from here.

I have try this scrolling issue with `Action class` but, same issue is getting replicated.

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement horizontal_scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='twc-scrollabe']/table"));
act.clickAndHold(horizontal_scroll).moveByOffset(40, 0).release().perform();
```

I have try with this below method also, but same issue is getting replicated.

```
WebElement horizontal_scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='twc-scrollabe']/table"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeScript(driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", horizontal_scroll));
```

In my application, I can not go with this method because there no `style` attribute is available inside `table` tag.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;     
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(''twc-scrollabe').setAttribute('style', 'position: relative; top: 0px; left: -658px; width: 1461px;')");
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help must be appreciated.
Best Regards,
Jainish Kapadia

Comment: I doubt your `//div[@id='twc-scrollable']/table` points at the scroller. If you have some specific element you should scroll towards, like a table cell, then you should find **the cell** and `scrollIntoView()` on it. NOT the table itself, since that is presumably already in view.

Comment: Just apply `scrollIntoView` to the last `th` element of the table...

Comment: @M.Prokhorov But scroll bar is inside the table and I can not able to locate only scroll bar. have you try this on your end?

Comment: Of course not, because I don't have your code. I can only infer from what I have seen in this question, and I can already tell, that you have selected a `<table>` element and act as if it's a scroll bar, which gets you this error.

Comment: @Andersson, Thnaks your hint is getting work for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use below for horizontal scroll

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;     
jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('table th:last-child').scrollIntoView();");
```

This should allow to scroll to the last column of the table

Comment: I have done with this code. `WebElement horizontal_scroll = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='twc-table']/..//following::th[@id='humidity']"));
     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", horizontal_scroll);`

Comment: Is there an equivalent in Python? I've a horizontal bar in my web page that I need to scroll so that other columns are visible.

Answer (score 0):

This works for both horizontal and vertical scroll if you need to scroll to the particular element

```
public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

(JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].offsetWidth", element);

Try above to scroll on extreme right - it worked for me. If you want to scroll on left change accordingly.