# Horizental Scrolling in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, protractor, gauge

I am working into an Angular Web Application where Some of the column Element properties will be visible after Scrolling only, So For scrolling, I have to scroll horizontally the grid which (Div container) is inside the Browser.

The HTML area is looking like below codes :

```
<div>class='ag-body-viewport-wrapper' role='presentation'</div>
<div>class='ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal' ref='ebodyviewport' role='presentation'</div>
<div>class='ag-body-viewport ag-layout-normal' ref='ebodycontainer' role='presentation' style='width height '</div>
<div>role = 'row' row id =''</div>
<div>role = 'row' row id =''</div>
```

Comment: where is your code? Div should have scroll bar automatically if its contents overflows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do horizontal scroll using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507826/how-to-do-horizontal-scroll-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I have added the HTML area above , please check once .